# tar restore --listed-incremental timestamp is in the future

Tags: backup, tar, restore

I have some backups that were created using `tar` `--listed-incremental` features. When I restore the individual backups one after the other using `tar -xf archive.tar` I get no warnings but if I restore them using `tar --extract --listed-incremental --file archive.tar` I get time stamp is in the future warning on several files. Although I am restoring on a different machine, I have to say that the backups have been done a month ago so there cannot be anything related to differnt times on the computers. Finally when I look at the extracted files for which there was the warning they have a completely different time and date than those mentioned in the warning.
What is going on?

Comment: Be happy that you could restore the archive at all. GNU tar cannot restore incrementals unless the differences are trivial. Try to use a working backup method...

Comment: @schily Actually I am finding that `tar` is "buggy" with incrementals, I get restored older versions than those that were backed up. Even when I do not use `--listed-incremental` on restore I get old version of files. When I do the same on mac, it works perfectly and all up to date version are restored. But mac version does not support `--listed-incremental`. This begs the question, why even the official documentation suggests using `tar` for backups if it is unreliable?

Comment: If you like a working `tar` implementation that supports incrementals, use `star` from the `schilytools`. Note that this uses an own new concept since the GNU tar incremental concept is buggy already and cannot lead to a working implementation. GNU tar advertizes this function since 1992, but it did never work and bug reports in 2004, 2011, 2016 and 2018 did not cause any reaction from the GNU tar maintainers. Given the typical GNU bug reaction time, I expect a reaction in 2025. BTW: what time stamps do you get if you list the related archive?

Comment: BTW: Mac OS uses the `FreeBSD` based `libarchive` with a better code quality than GNU tar. `libarchive` supports more archive formats than `star`but offers less features than `star`. Did you check the sample script at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411324/is-it-possible-to-use-tar-for-full-system-backups/451834#451834 that verifies the GNU tar bug? Questions related to the GNU tar documentation should be addressed to the GNU tar maintainers. If you are interested, here is the `star` man page: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html