# GNU tar: How to mix include and exclude on when --listed-incremental is in effect?

Tags: tar, gnu-tar

I have a `tar` command where I need to mix "include" and "exclude" operations. This is - when not using `--listed-incremental` working perfectly, but not when combined with `--listed-incremental`:

### What I have tried:

- Setup test scenario

  ```
  /tmp/tartest$ rm * ; touch a b
  ```
- `--exclude a` *before* the include (the simple `a`) works as expected (`a` is excluded):

  ```
  /tmp/tartest$ gtar cvf test.tar --exclude a a b
  b
  ```
- Include (the simple `a`) *before* the `--exclude a`   works as expected (`a` is included):

  ```
  /tmp/tartest$ gtar cvf test.tar a --exclude a a b
  a
  b
  ```
- `--exclude a` *before* the include (the simple `a`) works as expected (`a` is excluded), even with `--listed-incremental` is in operation:

  ```
  /tmp/tartest$ rm snapshot ; gtar cvf test.tar --listed-incremental=snapshot --exclude a a b
  b
  ```
- Include (the simple `a`) *before* the `--exclude a` does *not* work as expected (`a` is *not* included) with `--listed-incremental` is in operation:

  ```
  /tmp/tartest$ rm snapshot ; gtar cvf test.tar --listed-incremental=snapshot a --exclude a a b
  b

  ### Where is a???
  ```
- For level-1 incremental backups, the same holds (but plays no role for this question).
- My version is 1.34:

  ```
  /tmp/tartest$ gtar --version
  tar (GNU tar) 1.34
  ```

I'm skipping mentioning more tests I have done (obviously my real command line is more complex).

### Question

GNU tar 1.34 is from March 2021. I cannot imagine that this very basic functionality is a long-term-bug in `tar`. I have browsed the `bug-tar` mailing list and found no relevant mention of "incremental", "include" or "exclude" whatsoever. What am I doing wrong; how do I have to fix my command line so `a` is included in the archive when it is present befor its respective `--exclude` on the command line?

Comment: The `--exclude` option to GNU `tar` is, as far as I can see, not documented as being order sensitive in the same way as, e.g., the `-C` option is. In fact, I find nothing that says GNU `tar` actually supports random argument order with filenames occurring in between options, or that it should treat the order of options and filenames in any particular way. Maybe you've just been lucky that it seems to have worked the way you expected so far. The synopsis says to list filenames at the end.

Comment: Fair enough, @Kusalananda. I had that idea about ordering the files and --excludes from some answer here. Guess that was wrong (I can't find it anymore though). https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124531/linux-tar-listed-incremental-untrustworthy?rq=1 sounds depressing as well, guess I'll turn away from gtar and use another tool for my backups.